# Postgresql query to check string break

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem to perform a search for numerical sequence break in postgresql, I need that, for example, if my seq column is out of sequence I will be notified by email, for example my sequence `is: 340,341,342` if it `is: 340 342,343` this with a sequence **failure**.

Comment: Details, details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next query to find anomalies:

```
select count(*) from (
  select id - (lag(id) over (order by id)) diff from tbl
) t where diff is not null and diff <> 1;
```

When result of the query not 0 anomaly found

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/20239d83da919bf069923f1d89c13615/)